# Почему не откатывается транзакция?

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, транзакции

Пробую пример из книги, где объясняется распределенная транзакция. Но у меня не получается повторить откат транзакции при выбросе исключения. Вот мое приложение:
POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

XAJpaConfig.java

```
import com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

import static org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.*;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class XAJpaConfig {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSourceA() {
        try {
            AtomikosDataSourceBean dataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
            dataSource.setUniqueResourceName("XADBMSA");
            dataSource.setXaDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource");
            dataSource.setXaProperties(xaAProperties());
            dataSource.setPoolSize(1);
            return dataSource;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties xaAProperties() {
        Properties xaProp = new Properties();
        xaProp.put("databaseName", "MUSICDB_A");
        xaProp.put("useSSL", false);
        xaProp.put("user", "prospring5_A");
        xaProp.put("password", "prospring5_A");
        return xaProp;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory");
        hibernateProp.put(JTA_PLATFORM, "com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform");
        // required by Hibernate 5
        hibernateProp.put(TRANSACTION_COORDINATOR_STRATEGY, "jta");
        hibernateProp.put(CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "jta");

        hibernateProp.put(AUTOCOMMIT, false);
        hibernateProp.put(FLUSH_BEFORE_COMPLETION, false);
        hibernateProp.put(DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        // this will work only if users/schemas are created first, use ddl.sql script for this
        hibernateProp.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
        hibernateProp.put(SHOW_SQL, true);
        hibernateProp.put(MAX_FETCH_DEPTH, 3);
        hibernateProp.put(STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, 10);
        hibernateProp.put(STATEMENT_FETCH_SIZE, 50);
        return hibernateProp;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory emfA() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSourceA());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.example");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("emfA");
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

}
```

ServicesConfig.java

```
package org.example;

import com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionService;
import com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
public class ServicesConfig {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServicesConfig.class);


    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "shutdownForce")
    public UserTransactionService userTransactionService(){
        Properties atProps = new Properties();
        atProps.put("com.atomikos.icatch.service", "com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory");
        return new UserTransactionServiceImp(atProps);
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    @DependsOn("userTransactionService")
    public UserTransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager(){
        UserTransactionManager utm = new UserTransactionManager();
        utm.setStartupTransactionService(false);
        utm.setForceShutdown(true);
        return utm;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("userTransactionService")
    public UserTransaction userTransaction(){
        UserTransactionImp ut = new UserTransactionImp();
        try {
            ut.setTransactionTimeout(300);
        } catch (SystemException se) {
            logger.error("Configuration  exception.", se);
            return null;
        }
        return ut;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JtaTransactionManager ptm = new JtaTransactionManager();
        ptm.setTransactionManager(atomikosTransactionManager());
        ptm.setUserTransaction(userTransaction());
        return ptm;
    }
}
```

SingerService.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

@Service("singerService")
@Repository
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class SingerService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "emfA")
    private EntityManager emA;

    @Transactional
    public Singer save(Singer singer) {
        if (singer.getId() == null) {
            emA.persist(singer);
            if (true) {
                throw new JpaSystemException(
                        new PersistenceException("Simulation of something going wrong.")
                );
            }
        }
        return singer;
    }
}
```

И сам запуск приложения в файле App.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ServicesConfig.class,
                XAJpaConfig.class);
        SingerService singerService = ctx.getBean(SingerService.class);
        Singer singer = new Singer();
        singer.setFirstName("John");
        singer.setLastName("Mayer");
        singer.setBirthDate(new Date(
                (new GregorianCalendar(1977, 9, 16)).getTime().getTime()));
        singerService.save(singer);
    }
}
```

Но в БД запись с певцом все равно сохраняется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Из какой книги?

Comment: @Roman C, Spring 5 для профессионалов. Но пример я немного изменила.

Comment: Что вы изменили?

Comment: @Roman C, я его упростила, чтобы здесь опубликовать, где именно проявляется ошибка. А так он изначально не работал в том виде, в котором представлен в книге.

Answer (score 0):

Методом проб и ошибок, оказалось, что диалект Hibernate должен быть org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect, потому что у меня 8 версия MySQL.Также пришлось из-за этого поменять версию Hibernate на 5.3.7.Final.